# Organising a big project - how is it done?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I understand that for smaller projects keeping methods in the main view controller (namely `viewDidLoad`) is the way forward, but for bigger projects im thinking this cant be the way apps are organised - the m file would be chuffing huge! also there would be thousands of declarations at the top! Im nowhere near building an app that big but i'm intrigued, would you put them in a separate file and call them when they're needed? or is it just a case of scroll past the declarations and use pragma marks to find what your looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Basically this is not a specific question for developing iOS applications, it's more of a  software architecture problem and requires more knowledge that can't be put in a single answer.

But to get hold of how things usually work, the project has to be planned by pen and paper first, since those are the developer's best tool, then when you've got the main parts of your project planned in a good manner, you start by plotting some [ERD](http://www.datanamic.com/support/lt-dez006-what-is-an-erd.html) of your main components, and decide what will each part be responsible of, then start coding from there a prototype version.

when you have a simple project up and running, you start cleaning up the code, planning even further, and start [testing your code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing), I can't describe how important testing is !

You'll also need software to manage your project (not the source code, but the project itself), something like [asana](http://asana.com) maybe to keep track of tasks and who does what.

In order to keep your code safe against overwriting by other people who are working with you, and to keep things managed across versions, you'll need to setup a [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) repository of some king, [Git](http://git-scm.com) is supported out of the box by XCode !

Now for the part of code writing, you need to learn some kind of pattern and follow it, iOS projects and most others now follow the [MVC structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which answers your question of how big the classes will get and how things will communicate together without turning into a mess !

Yes, you'll need pragmas and code trickery here and there, but you should always follow the patterns and conventions in order to keep things maintainable when projects grow !

again as I said, this is not anywhere near a good start, you need lots of experience and knowledge before you can actually work on huge projects, but it's something !

Keep up the good work, and always remember that you always have to ask questions, never be intimidated :)

**Edit 1**
Forgot to add a tip on reading about [Agile software development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) that's probably my last tip :)

Comment: +1 Good points, nice answer ;)